# Free Shipping rule is not getting applied

Tags: magento-1.9

Free Shipping rule is not getting applied via Promotions. On one-step checkout page or cart page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your first image

**Apply to Shipping Amount** should be "Yes"

Also make sure you have a cart with a subtotal of $40 or more

Comment: Actually, I tried that but didn't work. My issue is it is getting applied on local system but not on live server. I have same code & db in local, still it is working in local & not in live